# Jetty mapped to 2 urls for same handler?

Tags: java, jetty

When creating an embedded jetty instance and mapping a url pattern to a particular handler, is it possible to map multiple urls to the same servlet handler?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this should be possible (as it is possible also with webapps).

As you create a `ServletHandler` you can add multiple `ServletMapping`s via `addServletMapping()` to this handler.